# How to automatically credit amount from business account to private account using Paypal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

Using Technology- ASP.NET MVC razor.

***Requirement:-***
I have Business account I need to credit some amount to users account how to do ?

- I have all details for paypal business account
- I have only users PayPal Id
- There is not going to Paypal site while the payment process
- I need to payment return details
- All transaction process should back end process only

I am stuck for it.. how to solve this issue.

Could you please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) for that.